# PostgreSQL Check_Constraint for IP-Address as VARCHAR

Tags: postgresql, ip-address, check-constraints

my table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE "IP" (
    "ID" serial NOT NULL,
    "IP-Add varchar(15) NULL
);
```

I'like to create a Check-Contraint for IPv4 Addresse to be
[1-255].[0-255].[0-255].[0-255]

I tried several options like

```
ALTER TABLE "IP" ADD CONSTRAINT "TBL_IP-Add_check" 
CHECK ("IP-Add" IS NULL OR "IP-Add" LIKE '^[1-255].^[1-255].^[1-255]');
```

Even when the syntax was accepted, after that I could no longer enter data,
Anybody to advice me?

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Why don't you use the `inet` datatype?

Comment: I've tried this, but it is not supported by the backend or the connector between both.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_name

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cast to an `inet` type:

```
ALTER TABLE "IP" ADD CONSTRAINT "TBL_IP-Add_check" 
CHECK ("IP-Add" IS NULL OR "IP-Add"::inet is not null);
```

But defining the column with the type `inet` type would be a much better solution.

Comment: Thank you, this check clause is the solution for me.